# Enable editing option is not display in gridview

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I took Datasource and configure Connection String. From Advance option I have selected "generate Insert, Update, Delete Statements" but after configuration of datasource with gridview display only 
- "Enable Deleteing"
- "Enable Shorting"
- "Enable paging"
- "Enable Selection"

**but not showing me *Enable Editing* option to gridview.**

what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

The Enable Editing check box appears in the smart tag panel only if the data source control to which GridView control is bound supports editing. For example, if the GridView control is bound to a SqlDataSource control, the SqlDataSource control's UpdateQuery property must contain a SQL Update statement.

To enable default editing using the AutoGenerateEditButton property
Select the GridView control, and in the Properties window, set AutoGenerateEditButton to true.

or

In Source view, in the  element, set AutoGenerateEditButton to true, as in the following example:

```
<asp:GridView Runat="server" ID="GridView1" 
  AutoGenerateEditButton="true" />
```

Comment: I have only one column in Database table named "ClassroomNo". How can I write update query in "UpdateQuery" property.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?
You need to show some effort or else show some code

Answer (score 0):

You can just write the UpdateCommand and DeleteCommand in the "SqlDataSource" tag.
This is an example that you can base on:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TechFocusConnectionString %>" 
  SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Comments]" 
  DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Comments] WHERE CodeCommentaire =@CodeCommentaire " 
  UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Comments] set Membre=@Membre, Article=@Article, Commentaire=@Commentaire, spam=@spam where CodeCommentaire =@CodeCommentaire">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

You can see there is the `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` where you can write down your own deleting or editing query and automatically the Deleting and Editing Options will be available. just don't forget to set the where clause with the primary key of your table, or else once you edit for example, all the rows will be edited.